# Retrieving a list from a database query with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to return a list with entity framework

```
using (FinalDatabaseEntities fdb = new FinalDatabaseEntities())
{
    var result = from Port in fdb.Ports select Port.Name;
    result = result.ToList();
}
```

I wish to return a list or array (list preferably) and place it in my `result` variable

I'm getting the following error

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   Finally!!   C:\Users\Kudzai Mhlanga\source\repos\Finally!!\Program.cs   22  Active

Comment: so what is the actual issue ?

Comment: do `result = fdb.Ports.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();`

Comment: I would recommend using @Aarif 's suggestion, but if you don't want to change your code too much: `var result = (from Port in fdb.Ports select Port.Name).ToList();`

Comment: So add it into the question

Comment: sure thanks @Stucky

Comment: @user8767324 add this error message to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a second local variable, which also makes your code more readable, since the first line creates a "query" not a "result".  So:

```
using (FinalDatabaseEntities fdb = new FinalDatabaseEntities())
{
    var query = from Port in fdb.Ports select Port.Name;
    var result = query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code will be :

```
using (FinalDatabaseEntities fdb = new FinalDatabaseEntities())
{
     var result = (from port in fdb.Ports  select port.Name).ToList();                      
}
```